# Problems rejecting edits

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Wasn't sure where to ask about this, but when I review a proposed edit and want to reject it for any reason besides "causes harm" I can't do it. Hitting the reject button just causes an error. If I select "causes harm" and fill in the description box I can make the reject button work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I was the other party to reject the edit, and it would not let me check anything other than "Causes Harm", either.

Comment: Same problem here. I couldn't choose spam/vandalism.

Comment: So this sounds like a bug. Who do we report bugs to?

Comment: Consider it reported. Did this happen only with the one edit, or is it happening continually?

Comment: Three times for me so far.

Comment: It happened a number of times. Since most edits can be approved, I don't know for how long this problem exists.

Comment: Same here - a number of times. I wasn't even able to reject a user's edit of my answer.

Comment: This happened today with a spam edit.  I had to reject using "Custom"

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the report.  I have found and fixed the issue - there was a lookup table that was out of sync for just the biology database.

Comment: Great, thanks for solving this.